# angular2-multiselect dropdown selects all boxes on clicking 1 checbkox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multi-select

```html
<angular2-multiselect 
         [data]="dataList | OrderBy : 'clientName'" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems[dataList.clientId]" 
         [settings]="dropdownSettings" name="multiSelect"
        
         (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event, dataList.clientId)" 
         (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event,dataList.clientId)"
         (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
         (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" disabled>
    
  <c-item>
     <ng-template let-item="item">
       <label style="color: #333;min-width: 160px;">{{item.clientName}}- {{item.clientId}}</label>
     </ng-template>
</c-item> 

</angular2-multiselect>
```

dataList is the list that is coming from backend evrything is working fine except the checkbox in dropDown..i am not able to select 1 checkbox as it selects all on clicking 1 cb also.

Comment: could you reproduce the issue on stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/ and share the link here

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish with "ng-multiselect-dropdown"

Installation :

```
npm install ng-multiselect-dropdown
```

And then include it in your module (see app.module.ts):

```
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
// ...

@NgModule({
imports: [
NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot()
// ...
]
// ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Usage

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
dropdownList = [];
selectedItems = [];
dropdownSettings = {};
ngOnInit() {
this.dropdownList = [
  { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Mumbai' },
  { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Bangaluru' },
  { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
  { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' },
  { item_id: 5, item_text: 'New Delhi' }
];
this.selectedItems = [
  { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
  { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' }
];
this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'item_id',
  textField: 'item_text',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 3,
  allowSearchFilter: true
};
}
onItemSelect(item: any) {
console.log(item);
}
onSelectAll(items: any) {
console.log(items);
}
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
[placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
[data]="dropdownList"
[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
[settings]="dropdownSettings"
(onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
(onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

For more details please check the URL -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: issue is resolved..but dropDown scrollBar is not showing in IE. Please suggest.

Comment: It is working for me for IE versions 9 and above. Are you asking about Microsoft Edge? Plz confirm.

Comment: no buddy i am asking about IE only..the dropDown is freezed in IE

Comment: IE11 i am using

Comment: It is working fine for me in IE 11. However it is not working for me in IE Edge. I added the below code in the CSS and it worked for me. Check if it works for you - .item2{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: Sure I will check it

Answer (score 0):

u have to add `primaryKey` in settings, like:

```
this.dropdownSettings = { 
                          singleSelection: false, 
                          text:"Select Countries",
                          selectAllText:'Select All',
                          unSelectAllText:'UnSelect All',
                          enableSearchFilter: true,
                          classes:"myclass custom-class",
                          **primaryKey**:**"your_identifier"**,
                        };
```

Related to:
https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/issues/252